# Calling Python Google Cloud Function via HTTP

Tags: python, http, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to call my Google Cloud Function via HTTP to get a response back in my browser. I expect a list of text, but am getting `Error: could not handle the request.`

Here's our code in the main.py source:

```
import openai

def gptinput(number,question,q_fc='q'):
    #user_information = firebase.FirebaseReader()
    openai.api_key = "___"
quest = "create '"+str(number)+ "' questions related to '"+question+"' with 4 options and print answer as ('ANSWER') and seperate each question with '/////'"
# Generate text using GPT-3
output_lis = []
while(len(output_lis)<number):

  response = openai.Completion.create(
      engine="text-davinci-002",
      prompt= quest,
      max_tokens=2048,
      n=1,
      stop=None,
      temperature=0.5
      )
      # Extract the generated text
  
  generated_text = response["choices"][0]["text"]
  ans = generated_text.split("/////")
  for i in ans:
    q = i.split('?')
    options= q[1][0:q[1].find("ANSWER")]
    answer = q[1][q[1].find("ANSWER")+6:]
    answer = answer.strip()
    
    option_lis = options.split('\n')
    option_lis.append(answer)
    
    ques = q[0].strip()
    option_lis = [s for s in option_lis if (s!='' or s!="")]
    option_lis1 = [s for s in option_lis if (s!="\n" )]

    output_lis.append({ques:option_lis1})
    
return output_lis[0:number]
  `
```

Comment: you are encountering is likely due to an issue with the configuration or setup of the Google Cloud Function. It could be caused by an issue with the openai api key or the google cloud function might not have access to the internet.

Comment: Have you checked the function logs for complete error logs? Can you share those as well?